# Removing multiple children from the stage if the item is on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Good afternoon.

I'm making a game, and in games as you know, when you destroy an object, you must remove it from the stage.

My enemies have been added dynamically, via code and if the user goes back the enemy would still be in the display list.

I have attempted to remove enemies by trying this code.

```
            removeChild(character); /removes player

            removeChild(ground); // removes ground
```

childrenOnStage is a number which equals this.numChildren

```
            for (var b:int = 0; b  < childrenOnStage; b++)
            {   
                if (getChildAt(b).name == "enemy")
                {
                    removeChild(getChildAt(b));
                }

            }
```

When the user goes back to the main menu from the game, it runs this code.

The code loops though the all of the children on the stage, and those that have the name enemy should be removed.

But I get an error

```
[Fault] exception, information=RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
```

My question is, how can I remove these enemies?

What if the enemy has been removed, this will cause more errors such as "null object" i.e enemy is not on stage, so why should I remove this enemy if it's not on?

Thank you.

Update due to Chernivs answer

```
        //after adding all of the children, this must be updated last
        childrenOnStage = this.numChildren;


    private function fromLevtoStart(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (e.target == backBtn1)
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, level1)
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop)
            //container.removeChild(_character);
            removeChild(character);
            removeChild(ground);
            for (var b:int = 0; b  < childrenOnStage; b++)
            {   
                if (getChildAt(b).name == "enemy")
                {
                    removeChild(getChildAt(b));

                    //childrenOnStage --;
                                            //update the variable below
                    childrenOnStage = this.numChildren;


                }

            }
            this.gotoAndStop("Start");
        }
    }
```

This still doesn't remove all of the enemies, but only one for some reason.

it should loop through all of the children on stage that have the name enemy and remove them, but it doesn't.

After trying the asnwer below I can say that it only removes goblin1 which is named "enemy" and typ Goblin.

```
        goblin1 = new Goblin();
        goblin1.name = "enemy";

        goblin2 = new Goblin();
        goblin2.name = "enemy";
```

When I kill goblin1 it gets removed, then when I go back to the start screen goblin 2 doesn't  even though that's the only goblin left with the name "enemy" it appears only goblin1 is targetted for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the name property, check the type of the display object. For example:

```
if(getChildAt(b) is Goblin) {
    //remove
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens, it only removes goblin1.

Comment: Whenever you remove a Goblin, decrease `b` with 1.

Comment: I understand why now, thank you minus b so we can minus that enemy off the loop, so it can search for more. Thank you to yo uand everyone!

Comment: Nope, the thing is, that if you remove the 5th enemy, then the 6th will be the 5th, thus the cycle will skip 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, decreasing the variable should work. But if you get any problems with what you've removed, you can do this:

```
var enemies:Array = new Array();
for (var b:int = 0; b  < childrenOnStage; b++) {
    var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(b);
    if (child.name == "enemy") {
        enemies.push(child);
    }
}

trace(enemies);
```

See what you get. Loop through `enemies` and remove each of them - this way you won't need to decrease any variable nor think about numChildren - simply remove everything that is 'marked' as an enemy.

Comment: Thank you but this only removes one enemy. I do not see the problem since I have named both enemies "enemy";

Comment: goblin1 = new Goblin();
   goblin1.name = "enemy";
   
   goblin2 = new Goblin();
   goblin2.name = "enemy";

Comment: That's why you should trace the array and check what's going on. If the array has a single item in it - it means the naming goes somehow wrong.
@Zhafur's answer has a better checking, you can try that too